# Laravel TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Tymon\JWTAuth\JWTGuard: :login() must implement interface Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject

Tags: laravel, authentication, jwt, token

I am getting this error and I can not find any solution however I am just searching and searching all day long like a week ago.

error I get from Backend:

> TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Tymon\JWTAuth\JWTGuard: :login() must implement interface Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject, instance of Illuminate\Auth\GenericUser given, called in C:\Users\XY\lartest\api\vendor\tymon\jwt-auth\src\JWTGuard.php on line 127 in file C:\Users\XY\lartest\api\vendor\tymon\jwt-auth\src\JWTGuard.php on line 140

And error from the Frontend:

> 500 Internal server error

User.php:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;


class User extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    /**
     * Get the identifier that will be stored in the subject claim of the JWT.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getJWTIdentifier() {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    /**
     * Return a key value array, containing any custom claims to be added to the JWT.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getJWTCustomClaims() {
        return [];
    }
}
```

api.php:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\AuthController;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use \App\Http\Controllers\UserController;
Route::group([

    'middleware' => 'api',
    'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers',
    'prefix' => 'auth'

], function ($router) {

    Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');
    Route::post('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
    Route::post('refresh', 'AuthController@refresh');
    Route::post('me', 'AuthController@me');

});
```

AuthController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;

class AuthController extends Controller implements JWTSubject
{
    /**
     * Create a new AuthController instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login']]);
    }

    /**
     * Get a JWT via given credentials.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function login()
    {
        $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);

        if (! $token = auth()->attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
        }

        return $this->respondWithToken($token);
    }

    /**
     * Get the authenticated User.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function me()
    {
        return response()->json(auth()->user());
    }

    /**
     * Log the user out (Invalidate the token).
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function logout()
    {
        auth()->logout();

        return response()->json(['message' => 'Successfully logged out']);
    }

    /**
     * Refresh a token.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function refresh()
    {
        return $this->respondWithToken(auth()->refresh());
    }

    /**
     * Get the token array structure.
     *
     * @param  string $token
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    protected function respondWithToken($token)
    {
        return response()->json([
            'access_token' => $token,
            'token_type' => 'bearer',
            'expires_in' => auth()->factory()->getTTL() * 60
        ]);
    }

    public function getJWTIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }
    public function getJWTCustomClaims()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

auth.php contains:

```
'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'api',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'jwt',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],

        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'users',
        ],
    ],
```

Comment: i think these:
`   public function getJWTIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }
    public function getJWTCustomClaims()
    {
        return [];
    }`
Must be declared inside User Model

Comment: It is defined there as you can see but because I get the same error I just implemented inside AuthController too

Answer (score 1):

Update your user model to implement the JWTSubject class:

```
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;

class User extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject {
//....
}
```